# A better name for this community, part 1

Tags: discussion, scope, meta, site-name

## Request to non-members

If you are not registered or have the minimal reputation required to post an answer, please consider joining [The Bright Tree Village](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/rub%C3%A9n-rivera-6b6271276_community-building-writing-activity-7064619273121329153-sixD?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop), a LinkedIn group I created on May 17, 2023. You can share suggestions and ask questions about participating in the group.

## Request to the Community

Please propose a better **site topic** wording and site blurb (high-level **scope**). The site name will be discussed after choosing an answer according to the Stack Exchange self-governance policies.

Answers should have the following structure.

```
# Topic 
   {Replace this with the topic; current topic: web applications.}
# Who is this site for *The site is for*
   {Replace this with the site blurb; current site blurb: Q&A for power users of web applications.}
# Link to a chatroom or external site
    *Space where the community interested in supporting this proposal might join in refining this proposal* 
    {Replace this with a link or instructions to join the community.}
```

Please

1. Write the topic in a brief but specific way. Privilege precision over using simple words.
2. Write the scope (who is this site for) in a brief but specific way addressing it to a broad audience (anyone on the web) the best you can.
3. You might add references or explanations before the suggested structure. Use a proper section separator like a horizontal line or use headings.

The site topic can't be radically different; it still should be about web applications. We are looking for better wording to help people understand what is on-topic, i.e., questions about programming beyond what an end-user can do, developing web applications, and creating and administering websites, are still off-topic. If possible, avoid using Technology Information jargon like "power user", "end user", and "citizen development" in the *site topic* and *site scope*. You could use words like this in an additional section.

### Background

This post is derived from a collage of concerns about the current situation of  Web Applications Stack Exchange and from the demand to make more evident the collaborative approach.

**Web Applications Stack Exchange** was created because web application questions were declared unsuitable for Super User. It was proposed in 2010 by Ivo Flipse, a Super User moderator. Jeff Atwood, one of the Stack Overflow founders, fully supported this proposal.

Area 51 creation site proposal form asks for the site topic, not the site name. When this site was created, Discussion Zone, the equivalent to *per-site-meta*, didn't exist, and the site name was something to be defined during the beta. The topic was

> Web Applications

For some reason, the site blurb thas set as "Q&A for web applications power users" even though the proposed scope was

> Q&A site for expert and advanced users of web applications.

The thought at that time was probably that the community might discuss it during the beta, but that didn't happen.

The initial name used for the site was "Web Applications". During the beta, the community decided to name the site "Nothing to Install", but this was *unilaterally* reverted by the company one day after the site graduated.

### Current Site Proposal Process

Since 2010, community-driven site proposals have been handled in Area 51.

At some point, the *Create Site proposal* form was modified to require a link to a webpage related to an existing community "ready and eager to build the site". It's unlikely that a site like Web Applications proposal will be approved nowadays.

Create site proposal fields:

> Choose a topic in "Technology":
>
> Who is this site for?
>
> > *This site is for*
>
> Please link to the organization or website organizing this effort:
>
> > *If you do not yet have a community organized, ready and eager to build your site, please do not submit this proposal.*

### Addendum

#### Create Technology Proposal at Area 51

Below is a screenshot of the current form to create a site proposal in the Area 51 technology category, taken on May 16, 2023.

[image: Create Technology Proposal at Area 51]

### Related

- [As of today, May 2023, who do we understand is our intended audience, and what is the first we tell them about participating?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5012)
- [Clarify "Ask Question" placeholder text](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4140/clarify-ask-question-placeholder-text)
- [Proposal to clean up the scope of the site: Is your question about using a specific web application?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/764/proposal-to-clean-up-the-scope-of-the-site-is-your-question-about-using-a-speci)
- [Should webapps.stackexchange.com be renamed?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2455)
- [Webapps.stackexchange.com versus Nothingtoinstall.com - Web Applications Meta Stack Exchange](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/webapps-stackexchange-com-versus-nothingtoinstall-com)
- [What's the difference between webapps and superuser?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326/whats-the-difference-between-webapps-and-superuser)

- [Who do outsiders think Web Applications is for, developers/power-users or Joe-user?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/731/88163)

### References

#### Super User Meta

- [Super User website applications policy](https://meta.superuser.com/q/821/152004)
- [Superuser off-topic restrictions](https://meta.superuser.com/q/1132/152004)

#### Super User Blog

- [Meet Ivo… ♦ Super User Mod ♦](https://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/11/meet-ivo-super-user-mod/)

#### Meta Stack Exchange

##### Policies

- [Standardizing & Simplifying SE Site Names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207404/289691)

Comment: "During the beta, the community decided to name the site "Nothing to Install", but this was unilaterally reverted by the company one day after the site graduated." I would like to read more about this event - on which meta post was this discussed, including the reversion by SE?

Comment: @galacticninja Start looking at [Webapps.stackexchange.com versus Nothingtoinstall.com](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/624/88163), [Nothingtoinstall redirects to webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/632/88163)

Comment: I see. Seems that there was no "unilateral reversion" of the site name by SE. They just didn't implement the name change suggestion.

Comment: @galacticninja: See the 2010 blog post about this: [Domain Names: The Wrong Question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/05/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

Comment: The link that you provided to the "Bright Tree Village" leads to a LinkedIn page that says "Something went wrong". Here's the link again: https://www.linkedin.com/posts/rub%C3%A9n-rivera-6b6271276_community-building-writing-activity-7064619273121329153-sixD?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop

Answer (score 6):

> Topic {Replace this with the topic; current topic: web applications.}

#### Topic: **Web Applications**

Notes: [If it ain't broke, don't fix it](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_it_ain%27t_broke,_don%27t_fix_it). Web Applications as a topic is already clear and straightforward.

---

> Who is this site for *The site is for*  {Replace this with the site blurb; current site blurb: Q&A for power users of web applications.}

#### Who is this site for: **Q&A site for users of web applications**

Notes: Changed "power users" to "users" as per the top-voted answers in the meta posts: [Who do outsiders think Web Applications is for, developers/power-users or Joe-user?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/732/7584) and [As of today, May 2023, who do we understand that is our intended audience and what is the first that we tell them about how to participate?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5013/7584)

---

> Link to a chatroom or external site
> *Space where the community interested in supporting this proposal might join in refining this proposal*
> {Replace this with a link or instructions to join the community.}

Link to a chatroom or external site: [Web Applications SE site tour](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) | [Web Applications SE Meta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/) | [Web Applications SE Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=webapps.stackexchange.com)

Notes: I'm not sure why we are asked to suggest external sites and instructions to join the community. The site tour and the help center are sufficient for onboarding new users, and if they have further questions, they can ask in meta.

Answer (score 3):

- Topic: questions about any website as an end-user and not a developer/webmaster/sysadmin/etc.
- Who is this site for: anyone (e.g., no need to be a "power user" to be allowed to participate).